# multiple icons expand gridview

Tags: javascript, asp.net, gridview

I'm trying to have 2 differents icons on my GridView.
(there is `Table ID="gvOrders"` and `Table ID="gvOrders2"` on same level)

```
<form id="form1" runat="server">
        <div style="overflow-x: hidden; overflow-y: hidden; width: 100%; height: 100%; margin-left: 147px;">
            <asp:GridView ID="gvCustomers" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false" CssClass="Grid" DataKeyNames="ABI" OnRowDataBound="OnRowDataBound">
                <Columns>
                    <asp:TemplateField>
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <img alt = "" style="cursor: pointer" src="pics/plus.png" />
                            <asp:Panel ID="pnlOrders" runat="server" Style="display: none">
                                <asp:Table ID="gvOrders" runat="server" CssClass = "ChildGrid">

                                </asp:Table>
                            </asp:Panel>
                        </ItemTemplate>
                    </asp:TemplateField>
                    <asp:TemplateField>
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <img alt = "" style="cursor: pointer" src="pics/plus.png" />
                            <asp:Panel ID="pnlOrders2" runat="server" Style="display: none">
                                <asp:Table ID="gvOrders2" runat="server" CssClass = "ChildGrid">

                                </asp:Table>
                            </asp:Panel>
                        </ItemTemplate>
                    </asp:TemplateField>

                </Columns>
            </asp:GridView>
            </div>
    </form>
```

and the js

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $("[src*=plus]").live("click", function ()
    {
        $(this).closest("tr").after("<tr><td></td><td colspan = '999'>" + $(this).next().html() + "</td></tr>")
        $(this).attr("src", "pics/minus.png");
    });
    $("[src*=minus]").live("click", function ()
    {
        $(this).attr("src", "pics/plus.png");
        $(this).closest("tr").next().remove();
        alert($(this).attr("src"));
    });
</script>
```

my question:
could be possible to have an icon for `'gvOrders'` and one for `'gvOrders2'`?

thanks in advance!

Comment: I can't see why not.  I personally would recommend http://getbootstrap.com/components/ which means you could use Glyphicons (which are very clean/good looking icons) which can be placed in your 'style' tag.

Comment: hi, thanks for your reply..but how i have to modify the js? $("[src*=plus]").live("click", function () work for both tables..